# BigVideo wait for loading

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, preloading

Is it real to do some preload, before show video with `BigVideo jQuery` plugin ?
Something like this `http://www.sabotagethefilm.com/`.
When i visite my web, video start playing automatically, and browser start really lagging cause they try to load and show in one time video.

I tryed tryied this construction, but nothing happened.

```
$(function() {
        var BV = new $.BigVideo();
        BV.init();
        if (Modernizr.touch) {
            $("#big-video-wrap").css({display: 'none'});
        } else {
            BV.show('../video/mp4_koe12_light8.mp4',{preload: true, ambient: false});
        }
    });
```

Comment: When i should start playing?

Comment: After some preloading, like on `http://www.sabotagethefilm.com/`, there go loading line, and after some secunds opens video and playing.

Comment: You should call stop function first and then play i think can you make fiddle?

Comment: But how i can know when video will loading at least a little ?
I mean if i will start video automatically after 20sec for all users, then people with fast internet connection will get normall video, but if somebody have slow connection, then 20sec didnt help them at all ?

Comment: You can check there, `http://zadarom-film.ru/index.php` please.)

Comment: You can use some library as video.js and use its API (events) to check when all video is loaded or is in progress, meanwhile you can show a progress bar or whatever you want